# Authorization_RequestDenied on Azure Graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have developed one Oauth flow for a web application that works successfully with my App Registration and Enterprise Application.

But I am now mapping it to my customer and I keep getting an error when trying to get the profile (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me).
All I need is the user's email, and I do not request to write anything.

The response I get is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-04-13T15:38:42",
            "request-id": "xxxxx-0300-4c22-a1ed-xxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxx-0300-4c22-a1ed-xxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

During the authentication flow, my application asks me to grant read access to my profile. But my customer's also asks to "maintain something", even though I only put in scope the profile (`&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/profile`)

Any idea what setup my customer needs to change on Azure?

Answer (score 2):

The error `Authorization_RequestDenied` usually occurs when you don't have proper permissions to perform that action.

As per this **[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)**, you need ***Delegated*** **`User.Read`** permission while calling user profiles with **`/me`** endpoint in your query:

> **1. Calling the /me endpoint requires a signed-in user and therefore a
> delegated permission. Application permissions are not supported when
> using the /me endpoint**.
>
> **2. The User.Read permission allows the app to read the profile, and
> discover relationships such as the group membership, reports and
> manager of the signed-in user only.**

After registering application in Azure Active Directory, make sure to **grant** API permissions like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your Application -> API Permissions -> Add a Permission -> Microsoft Graph***

[image: 1]
[image]

Please note that **Users.Read** don't need any admin consent whereas **Users.Read.All** need **[admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#:%7E:text=%20To%20grant%20tenant-wide%20admin%20consent%20to%20an,agree%20with%20the%20permissions%20the%20application...%20More%20?msclkid=0d8b2d84bced11ec804e5a7b06077f4d)**.

To know more in detail, please refer below **links** if they are helpful:

["Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" while using Graph API - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197819/34insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operatio.html?msclkid=6061f6b8bce411eca5d5c54843e4aba4)

["code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/577678/34code3434authorization-requestdenied3434message34-1.html?msclkid=6061cc9dbce411eca99a8cc71289a2eb)

Comment: its there, but the error keeps happening

Comment: The solution after all was to change the scope.....
`&scope=openid%20offline_access` this is what made it work

Answer (score 0):

If the customer is from a different AD tenant, you need to reconfigure your registered app to support multiple organisations:

[image]

Comment: The flow works with my app, but not on the customer's app

Comment: Updated answer above

Comment: My azure account is not the same as the customer's....

Comment: You need multi-tenant option enabled. See above.

Comment: it is enabled....

Comment: Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration